# Save Image To Phone? WP7 C#

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to make an app with images that you can save to your phone. I don't even know where to begin. What is the simplest way to do this in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [**article**](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2010/08/14/Windows-Phone-7-Beta-How-do-I-save-an-image-to-the-Pictures-Hub.aspx) explains on how you can save a newly taken photo to the Pictures Hub.
 And [**this one**](http://windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-Images) is about saving to the IsolatedStorage. This should get you started!

If you still have completely no idea what this is all about (since you say you're are an amateur), I suggest you read a couple of articles on Windows Phone 7 development first. On the [**App Hub**](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/quickstarts) are lots of articles and tutorials with **code samples** on dozens of topics to get started with Windows Phone 7 development. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Download the image, and save to the Isolated storage, also you can add it to the Picture Collection also.

This is idea to make it, you can break the idea into parts and achieve the same.

Comment: I am an amateur programmer, could you please give example code?

Comment: You can refer the following thread . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142169/how-can-i-download-and-save-images-from-the-web