# How to store image on button click in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing an application which has many images & i want to implement that on clicking "save button" the Image should be stored to Photo Album.

Please reply i am new to app dev.

Comment: What's the source of image?

Comment: Images are present in the Assets folder of my project & displayed in panorama view.

Comment: Don't know where from you are getting the images. But hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142169/how-can-i-download-and-save-images-from-the-web

Answer (score 1):

To work with this function you just need to pass needed Image as parameter in SaveImageToPhotoHub function.
    private bool SaveImageToPhotoHub(WriteableBitmap bmp)
        {

```
        using (var mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary())
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var fileName = string.Format("Gs{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid());
                bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var picture = mediaLibrary.SavePicture(fileName, stream);
                if (picture.Name.Contains(fileName)) return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Heres more to it http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/747273/How-to-Save-Image-in-Local-Photos-album-of-Windows

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. This is in VB.Net but I am sure you can convert it yourself or through online tools for C#:

```
    ' Create a file name for the JPEG file in isolated storage.
    Dim tempJPEG As String = "dummyImage1"

    ' Create a virtual store and file stream. Check for duplicate tempJPEG files.
    Dim myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
    If myStore.FileExists(tempJPEG) Then
        myStore.DeleteFile(tempJPEG)
    End If

    Dim myFileStream As IsolatedStorageFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(tempJPEG)


    ' Create a stream out of the sample JPEG file.
    ' For [Application Name] in the URI, use the project name that you entered 
    ' in the previous steps. Also, TestImage.jpg is an example;
    ' you must enter your JPEG file name if it is different.
    Dim sri As StreamResourceInfo = Nothing
    Dim uri As New Uri("/projectName;component/Assets/1.jpg", UriKind.Relative)
    sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri)

    ' Create a new WriteableBitmap object and set it to the JPEG stream.
    Dim bitmap As New BitmapImage()
    bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None
    bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream)
    Dim wb As New WriteableBitmap(bitmap)

    ' Encode WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream.
    wb.SaveJpeg(myFileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85)
    myFileStream.Close()

    ' Create a new stream from isolated storage, and save the JPEG file to the media library on Windows Phone.
    myFileStream = myStore.OpenFile(tempJPEG, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    ' Save the image to the camera roll or saved pictures album.
    Dim library As New MediaLibrary()

    ' Save the image to the saved pictures album.
    Dim pic As Picture = library.SavePicture("dummyImage1.jpg", myFileStream)
    MessageBox.Show("Image saved to saved pictures album")

    myFileStream.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found on something like that:source https://msdn.microsoft.com.

```
 // Informs when full resolution photo has been taken, saves to local media library and the local folder.
void cam_CaptureImageAvailable(object sender, Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = savedCounter + ".jpg";

    try
    {   // Write message to the UI thread.
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
            txtDebug.Text = "Captured image available, saving photo.";
        });

        // Save photo to the media library camera roll.
        library.SavePictureToCameraRoll(fileName, e.ImageStream);

        // Write message to the UI thread.
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
            txtDebug.Text = "Photo has been saved to camera roll.";

        });

        // Set the position of the stream back to start
        e.ImageStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // Save photo as JPEG to the local folder.
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream targetStream = isStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                // Initialize the buffer for 4KB disk pages.
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = -1;

                // Copy the image to the local folder. 
                while ((bytesRead = e.ImageStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    targetStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }

        // Write message to the UI thread.
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
            txtDebug.Text = "Photo has been saved to the local folder.";

        });
    }
    finally
    {
        // Close image stream
        e.ImageStream.Close();
    }

}

// Informs when thumbnail photo has been taken, saves to the local folder
// User will select this image in the Photos Hub to bring up the full-resolution. 
public void cam_CaptureThumbnailAvailable(object sender, ContentReadyEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = savedCounter + "_th.jpg";

    try
    {
        // Write message to UI thread.
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
            txtDebug.Text = "Captured image available, saving thumbnail.";
        });

        // Save thumbnail as JPEG to the local folder.
        using (IsolatedStorageFile isStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream targetStream = isStore.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                // Initialize the buffer for 4KB disk pages.
                byte[] readBuffer = new byte[4096];
                int bytesRead = -1;

                // Copy the thumbnail to the local folder. 
                while ((bytesRead = e.ImageStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    targetStream.Write(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
        }

        // Write message to UI thread.
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
            txtDebug.Text = "Thumbnail has been saved to the local folder.";

        });
    }
    finally
    {
    // Close image stream
    e.ImageStream.Close();
    }
}
```